# Why is header and body not encrypted when using HttpClient HTTPS requests?

Tags: c#, apache, http

Consider the following function:

```
private string ServerUrl = "https://api.myserver.com";

public async Task<T> PostRequest<T>(string hook, HttpContent content)
{
    try
    {
        var response = await http.PostAsync(ServerUrl + hook, content);
        var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return Serializer.ToJsonObject<T>(contentString);
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Now it works correctly, but as I'm making requests to HTTPS shouldn't header and body be encrypted?

I'm checking things with Fiddler v4 and it isn't.

Is there something I am missing or don't quite understand how that should work?

My server uses LetsEncrypt! Self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler can decrypt the content before it's displayed to you in the UI.  Do you have this setting enabled?

[image]

Comment: So that means that anyone who snipes it can easily decrypt it as well?

Comment: Fiddler can only intercept encrypted traffic if you have set up both Fiddler and your browser [a special way](https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp).  Normally the header and body cannot be intercepted.

Comment: @J. Doe No.  What happens is Fiddler installs certificates in your machine and does a Man in the Middle proxy connection (you get prompted to allow it).  Then it makes the HTTPS request on your behalf using its certificate.  It can then decrypt the HTTPS requests.  Someone without that certificate will not be able to decrypt it.